# What permission ffmpeg-static need in AWS Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, ffmpeg

I have this code. It download a image, made a video from it and upload it to S3. It runs on Lambda. Added packages, intalled, zipped, uploaded.

```
npm install --production
zip -r my-lambda-function.zip ./
```

But get an `error code 126`

```
2023-02-17T09:27:55.236Z    5c845bb6-02c1-41b0-8759-4459591b57b0    INFO    Error: ffmpeg exited with code 126
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:182:22)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
2023-02-17T09:27:55.236Z 5c845bb6-02c1-41b0-8759-4459591b57b0 INFO Error: ffmpeg exited with code 126 at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:182:22) at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28) at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
```

Do I need to set a specific premission for ffmpeg?

```js
import { PutObjectCommand, S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3'
import { fromNodeProviderChain } from '@aws-sdk/credential-providers'
import axios from 'axios'
import pathToFfmpeg from 'ffmpeg-static'
import ffmpeg from 'fluent-ffmpeg'
import fs from 'fs'
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(pathToFfmpeg)
const credentials = fromNodeProviderChain({
    clientConfig: {
        region: 'eu-central-1',
    },
})
const client = new S3Client({ credentials })

export const handler = async (event, context) => {
    try {
        let body
        let statusCode = 200
        const query = event?.queryStringParameters
        if (!query?.imgId && !query?.video1Id && !query?.video2Id) {
            return
        }

        const imgId = query?.imgId
        const video1Id = query?.video1Id
        const video2Id = query?.video2Id
        console.log(
            `Parameters received, imgId: ${imgId}, video1Id: ${video1Id}, video2Id: ${video2Id}`
        )
        const imgURL = getFileURL(imgId)
        const video1URL = getFileURL(`${video1Id}.mp4`)
        const video2URL = getFileURL(`${video2Id}.mp4`)
        const imagePath = `/tmp/${imgId}`
        const video1Path = `/tmp/${video1Id}.mp4`
        const video2Path = `/tmp/${video2Id}.mp4`
        const outputPath = `/tmp/${imgId}.mp4`
        await Promise.all([
            downloadFile(imgURL, imagePath),
            downloadFile(video1URL, video1Path),
            downloadFile(video2URL, video2Path),
        ])
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log('Input files downloaded')
            ffmpeg()
                .input(imagePath)
                .inputFormat('image2')
                .inputFPS(30)
                .loop(1)
                .size('1080x1080')
                .videoCodec('libx264')
                .format('mp4')
                .outputOptions([
                    '-tune animation',
                    '-pix_fmt yuv420p',
                    '-profile:v baseline',
                    '-level 3.0',
                    '-preset medium',
                    '-crf 23',
                    '-movflags +faststart',
                    '-y',
                ])
                .output(outputPath)
                .on('end', () => {
                    console.log('Output file generated')
                    resolve()
                })
                .on('error', (e) => {
                    console.log(e)
                    reject()
                })
                .run()
            
        })
        await uploadFile(outputPath, imgId + '.mp4')
            .then((url) => {
                body = JSON.stringify({
                    url,
                })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error)
                statusCode = 400
                body = error?.message ?? error
            })
        console.log(`File uploaded to S3`)
        const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://tikex.com, https://borespiac.hu',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
        }
        return {
            statusCode,
            body,
            headers,
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify('Error fetching data'),
        }
    }
}

const downloadFile = async (url, path) => {
    try {
        console.log(`Download will start: ${url}`)
        const response = await axios(url, {
            responseType: 'stream',
        })
        if (response.status !== 200) {
            throw new Error(
                `Failed to download file, status code: ${response.status}`
            )
        }
        response.data
            .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path))
            .on('finish', () => console.log(`File downloaded to ${path}`))
            .on('error', (e) => {
                throw new Error(`Failed to save file: ${e}`)
            })
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(`Error downloading file: ${e}`)
    }
}
const uploadFile = async (path, id) => {
    const buffer = fs.readFileSync(path)
    const params = {
        Bucket: 't44-post-cover',
        ACL: 'public-read',
        Key: id,
        ContentType: 'video/mp4',
        Body: buffer,
    }
    await client.send(new PutObjectCommand(params))
    return getFileURL(id)
}
const getFileURL = (id) => {
    const bucket = 't44-post-cover'
    const url = `https://${bucket}.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/${id}`
    return url
}
```

Added `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole-16e770c8-05fa-4c42-9819-12c468cb5b49` permission, with policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:eu-central-1:634617701827:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:eu-central-1:634617701827:log-group:/aws/lambda/promo-video-composer-2:*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sns:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What do I miss?

```
janoskukoda@Janoss-MacBook-Pro promo-video-composer-2 % ls -l $(which ffmpeg)
lrwxr-xr-x  1 janoskukoda  admin  35 Feb 10 12:50 /opt/homebrew/bin/ffmpeg -> ../Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2_4/bin/ffmpeg
```

Comment: Ensure that the `ffmpeg` command has execute permissions. You can do this by running `ls -l $(which ffmpeg)` command in your shell to check the file permissions

Comment: Do I need run it on my local machine? Seems there is `x` on it.

Comment: On Aws where your `ffmpeg-static` package installed inside node_modules folder

Comment: Ohk got it. So I think you need to check in that folder.